# Jquery calendar enable disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I have disabled past dates on jquery calendar now i want to reset calendar when i click on cancel button how can i do this below is my code i have tried date picker clearDate method but its not working for me please help.

```
$(function ()
 {
 $(".endDate").datepicker({
 minDate: 0, //disable past date
 dateFormat: "dd-M-yy" //date format
});
});
//button for reset calendar
 $(".resetCalendar").click(function()
{
 $.datepicker._clearDate(this); //this is not working
});
```

Comment: `$.datepicker.setDate( null)`

Comment: returns an error Error: $.datepicker.setDate is not a function

Comment: Which library are you using then? Not the one from jQuery UI?